# Starting Automator Script with LaunchAgent

Tags: macos, launchd

I built a job by Automator to clear the downloads folder and empty the trash. When i start the created app by double click, it starts correctly. But it has to be transferred to other computer in our company and i dont want to give the user the job to launch the app.
So i created this LaunchAgent script to start the app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.herpag.aufraeumen.plist</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/hansthiele/Applications/Aufraeumen.app</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>45</integer>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>13</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

My problem is now, that the console tells me that the job is started, but nothing happens. The downloads are not cleared and the trash is still full. Also the error.log is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

1. The `Label` argument must be specified without the `.plist` extension.
2. The path must represent the executable rather than the application container. In case of an Automator app the executable is named `Application Stub` (unlike `Applet` in an AppleScript app). It's assumed that `hansthiele` is the real short username of the current user.

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.herpag.aufraeumen</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/hansthiele/Applications/Aufraeumen.app/Contents/MacOS/Application Stub</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>45</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>13</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I tried the changes, but now i get a message "Could not find specified service", when i load or unload the script in the terminal. I dont get the message only when the Label contains the .plist.

Comment: In the `launchctl load` line the plist extension must be included, but not in the proper list file.

Comment: Now i found the error. It was not the .plist, but there was something missing in the path. It must be "Contents/MacOS/Application Stub". Now its working correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. Of course the executable is always in the folder `MacOS`